# Audio Input Programming

Tags: java, c++, audio, input

What im playing around with is out of the scope of the usual programming I do so I thought I would ask before I waste more time.

So basically I have a button (usually found on a computers ON/OFF switch) and using my not-so vast knowledge of electronics I have connected it to a standard audio cable (which is of course connected to my computers audio in jack). Through Audacity I have found that when I click the button an audio wave form is generated and picked up.

This is all very basic stuff, I left my Arduino back at my parents place so In desperation I have decided to use my sound card as a micro-controller.

Anyway I'm sure you all know where I am going with this.
How can I get to programming a little app that runs on Command Prompt(For testing) and as a background process that will monitor and process the information coming from the input to do certain task (Like locking my computer or opening up Firefox etc...)?

I work with Java as part of my Computing Degree(We are still learning very basic stuff... hence the question) and also work with PHP on a daily basis for work, so I don't mind learning a new language if I have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring this one out for myself. Basically its as easy as listening to the input line then running a method if the amplitude of the audio gets gets to a certain amount. Through testing I also found that the amplitude is measured in negative numbers when the button is clicked down and a positive amplitude is registered when the button is released. That means you can write code for those individual events and if you are smart enough you can also add an event for when the button is held down by using an interval timer.

Anyway here is the code (Unfortunately I have not had the time to comment it):

**AudioInputButton.java**

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info;


public class AudioInputButton {
  private int line;
  private AudioFormat format;
  private Info[] lines;
  private TargetDataLine inputLine;
  private DataLine.Info inInfo;
  private int bufferSize;

  public AudioInputButton(int line){
    this.line = line;
    this.setup();
  }

  public AudioInputButton(){
    this.line = 2;
    this.setup();
  }

  private void setup(){
    format = new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1, true, true); 
    lines = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();    
    inInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
  }

  public void printLineInfo(){
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
      System.out.println(i+": "+lines[i].getName()+"\n"+lines[i].getDescription());
    }
  }

  public void startListening(){
    try{
      inputLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getMixer(lines[line]).getLine(inInfo);
      inputLine.open(format, bufferSize);
      inputLine.start(); 

      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      System.out.println("Listening on line " +line+", " + lines[line].getName() + "...");

      while(true){
        inputLine.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
        int sample = listen(buffer);
        if(sample > 0){
          onClick();
        }
      }
    }catch (LineUnavailableException e){
      System.out.println("Line " + line + " is unavailable.");
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  public int listen(byte[] eightBitByteArray)
  {
    int index = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    boolean down = false;
    boolean up = false;
    for (int audioByte = 0; audioByte < eightBitByteArray.length;)
    {
      int low = (int) eightBitByteArray[audioByte];
      audioByte++;
      int high = (int) eightBitByteArray[audioByte];
      audioByte++;
      int sample = (high << 8) + (low & 0x00ff);
      if(sample < -1100){
        if(!down){
          onDown();
          ret = sample;
          down = true;
        }
      }else if(sample > 1100){
        if(!up){

          onUp();
          ret = sample;
          down = false;
          up = true;
        }
      }
      index++;
    }
    return ret;
  }

  private void onClick(){
    System.out.println("Click!");
  }

  private void onDown(){
    System.out.println("Down!");
  }

  private void onUp(){
    System.out.println("Up");
  }
}
```

**AudioInputButtonTester.java**

```
public class AudioInputButtonTester {
  public static void main (String [] args){
    AudioInputButton myButton = new AudioInputButton(2);
    myButton.startListening();
  }
}
```

I was going to turn the various button states into events so that you can write your code for them in the tester class but its 2:30 am and if you really want to separate your logic that create a new button class that extends AudioInputButton with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I think , this task can be standardized or simplified by using [COM port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port).

Check out these examples
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/COM-Port.htm
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/cookbook/11.pdf

If you want to do your task by using audio-in jack (Microphone input port), you have to check the input level of sound amplitude and do your task according to the intensity level. For this you have to get idea of multi-threading and recording sound in JAVA

Comment: Yea through my impatience I ended up finding a way to do it through good old Java. I am only trying this out for fun really.